# Query multiple mongodb collections in node app using Mongoose async

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose, find

In my `node.js` app I want to query multiple `mongodb` collections in a series using `mongoose` with the `async` plugin based on result from the first callback in the series.

So far I have this working code but I'm sure there is a better way of doing it async:

```
router.route('/project/:projectId')
    .get(function(req, res) {

        var getProjectDetails = function(cb) {
            models.Project.findById(req.params.projectId, function(err, project) {
                if(err)
                    res.send(err);
                models.Media.find({'project_code' : project.code },  function(err, media) {
                    cb(null, {'project' : project, 'media': media})
                });
            })
        }

        async.parallel([getProjectDetails], function(err, result) {
            res.render('details', {data: result});
        });
    });
```

As you can see I want to find all entries from the `Media` collection where `project_code` equals `code` from `Project` collection.

How can I acvhieve this without nesting my mongoose-querys?

Comment: I don't  think it will work for you, did you test? You are calling same function without any changes

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need async in this? I hope this will work.

```
router.route('/project/:projectId')
    .get(function(req, res) {

        models.Project.findById(req.params.projectId, function(err, project) {
           if(err)
               return res.send(err);
           models.Media.find({'project_code' : project.code },  function(err, media) {
               if(err)
                  return res.send(err);
               return res.render('details', {data: {'project' : project, 'media': media}});
           });
        });
});
```